# Position Fixed not working when CSS Filters applied on same element in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-filters

I am testing this on Edge 20.10240.16384.0

I have an element whose position is fixed and has CSS Filters applied to it. This works great in all browsers except Microsoft Edge, where the position of the element doesn't remain fixed. This issue is directly related to CSS3 Filters as removing them makes the position fixed work correctly

Here is a basic example of this. It works correctly (aka the fixed background remains fixed) on browsers other than Microsoft Edge.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 5000px;
    }
    
    .fixed {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      background-image: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-REJ8pezTyCQ/SDlvLzhAH-I/AAAAAAAABeQ/mC1PXNiheJU/s800/Blog_background_750.gif);
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
      -moz-filter: brightness(70%);
      -o-filter: brightness(70%);
      filter: brightness(70%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='fixed'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

After searching around , I came across https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1810480/ms-edge-rendering-problem-of-css-filter , which details the same issue but has been marked as Fixed most likely as it couldn't be reproduced. I am attaching GIF for the same -

**Microsoft Edge -**
[image]

**Google Chrome -**
[image]

Comment: Looks like there isn't a workaround. I haven't been able to find anything either and MS seems to not be able to reproduce it....

Comment: I can reproduce it given your example. I attempted changing width and height to use 100vw and 100vh, and set `bottom: 0px`, which at least caused it to seem to *sometimes* work when I fiddled the filter CSS rule on and off. Alt-tabbing between windows then occasionally got it working again, which certainly isn't good enough. I think this qualifies as an Edge bug.

Comment: @Katana314 I was able to workaround this issue by not applying position fixed and CSS filters both on the same element but otherwise as you suggest, the behaviour is very erratic

Comment: Your code snippet worked perfectly for me in Edge of the same version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a bug, [ms-edge-rendering-problem-of-css-filter](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1810480/ms-edge-rendering-problem-of-css-filter), should have been fixed but obviously not.

Here is a workaround, where you still can use `position: fixed` and the image and filter is set using the `:after` pseudo-element.

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-REJ8pezTyCQ/SDlvLzhAH-I/AAAAAAAABeQ/mC1PXNiheJU/s800/Blog_background_750.gif);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(70%);
  -o-filter: brightness(70%);
  filter: brightness(70%);
}
```

```html
<div class='fixed'></div>
```