# How to create this complex animation in my website, and make it responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I need to reproduce a similar effect of this: https://dribbble.com/shots/3275340-Exploring-The-North-Face in the home page of the website i am working on. I read some comments in this dribble link, and the creator said that the effect was made with Adobe After Effects, so maybe this effect is not completely doable in the web environment.

(**Old**) Currently the way-to-go is a custom svg path set to display only the content inside of it, like this question: [SVG viewbox overflow: hidden / crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074216/svg-viewbox-overflow-hidden-crop).

My first goal was resolving how to make the transition between the two words not linear, so i created an outline of the clouds with svg path. My problem with this code here it's that as soon as i leave my developement resolution (approximately 1900x920) of my monitor the svg path doesn't resize and gets pushed after the end of the image.

<strike>My problems right now are 2:</strike>

- **Resolved** <strike>Notice the transition over the two words, how it's not linear</strike>
- **Resolved** <strike>he responsiveness of this whole section, how it breaks just moving like 10px away from my screen's resolution</strike>

**Old** Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4kd36ya8/1/

**UPDATE**: I changed the whole code to try out another thing: CSS Masks (https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) and this seems to work very good with what I am trying to achieve. The problem is with the position of the words. If i put them in `position: fixed` there is a bug in Microsoft Edge (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780409/position-fixed-not-working-when-css-filters-applied-on-same-element-in-microsoft) question for reference; note that I already tried the fix that the post explains, but with no success at all).

**Current** Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ztgyq1kc/4/

**Current** Code:

```css
body {
  /* Just to make the document scroll over */
  height: 300vh;
}

.home-header {
  height: 100vh;
}
.home-header .inside {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/SN3Wjsx3/test.png");
  mask-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/SN3Wjsx3/test.png");
  z-index: 2;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cloud-writing {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12.5rem;
  letter-spacing: -1rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.cloud-writing.white {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}
.cloud-writing.blue {
  color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-header">
  <div class="inside">
    <div class="cloud-writing white">Text1</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080?text=placeholder" class="image" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="cloud-writing blue">Text2</div>
</div>
```

My next goal will be adding a parallax library (I still do not know which one) to handle all animations.